Como trabajar con Speech-to-Text en Flutterflow. Hace Falta documentacion
Habilite "Cloud Speech-to-Text API" en firebase; ahora me resulta muy complicado que funcione en mi app de Flutterflow. No se como hacerlo.
Intente hacer una funcion personalizada pero hay que saber codificar y Flutterflow es una plataforma que se vende con la idea de que no se necesita hacer codigo pero veo que sí se requiere codificar y yo no sé como hacer codigo. He didicado muchas horas navegar por la documentacion y no veo nada que facilite las cosas a los usuarios de Flutterflow. ¿Podrian ayudarme?

Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste  o investigaste, recisa [ask], saludos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
